# nginx load wordpress from a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I followed a guide from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install wordpress on my ubuntu server. Upon entering the url http://mydomain.com loads me the front page.

```
     server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    }
```

[image: Working wordpress]

I want to load wordpress from my subdomain i.e., http://mydomain.com/wordpress. I went on  to modify the location but it can't load properly (it still looks for files under http://mydomain.com).

```
    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /wordpress {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

or

```
    location /{
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

[image: Wordpress fails]

How do I fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your wordpress looking for his files in root directory. /
So you need to tell him, to search his files in the right directory. /wordpress/
There are two ways. 
Better: to change the path using wordpress config file for rewriting resources path

from

```
/css/*, /*    etc
```

to

```
/wordpress/css/*, /wordpress/*   and so on.
```

Worst: to redirect your wordpress resources to root directory. Something like this:

```
  location ~ ^/images/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri /wordpress/images/$uri =404;
    access_log off;
   }
```

Comment: wordpress installation directory doesn't have a simple index.php file where I can modify the CSS linked file. One php links other php that links to many other php files. It is too complicated to find which php file links CSS. I have to find a solution with redirect. It will be great if you can help me with that. thanks

Comment: Sorry for indistinct answer. I just want to say, I don't know WP very well, but I suppose it has some parameters in the config file which you can use to change the path for your resources. Actually, for the css, js files you can use <base> html tag, but I think it's a bit wrong way. 
I think you may find some help there http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress